# Django convert CBV to json

Tags: django, django-views, django-jsonfield

I have this CBV

```
class Ansicht(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'SCHUK/Ansicht.html'
    context_object_name = 'Ansicht'
```

Im using _set to display all users data to staff. But I need to use the data for calculations, how can I convert this to json

Comment: Django has a method for converting models to a dictionary. `from django.forms.models import model_to_dict`, then you can use `json.dumps`. You can override the `post()` or `get()` method of your view to implement the logic as you see fit. (Or optionally, `get_context_data` if it needs to be passed into a view.`)

Comment: how would I implement that, just normal def(self) and then instance.__dict__ ?

Comment: is it possible to convert it right from the model? with @property it works on Integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`model_to_dict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cd1afd553f9c175ebccfc0f50e72b43b9604bd97/django/forms/models.py#L93).

Then you can define a method on your model:

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
class MyModel...
    def get_json(self):
        return json.dumps(model_to_dict(self))
```

In your template, you can just call `{{instance.get_json}}`.